# How can I declare a 2D integer array of size 100000 by 100000 in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory-management, multidimensional-array, out-of-memory

I tried this using VS 2013. I got an exception saying "An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in byteArray.exe" (I used byte instead of int)
    .
    .

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
  byte[,] a = new byte[100000, 100000];
  for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<100000; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(0+" ");
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: As it said. You don't have enough memory to store such a big array like that.

Comment: Do you really have free 10GB RAM for this task?

Comment: No.. I have just 3GB RAM (Total). Does it need 10GB ?

Comment: @VikasThakur you should calculate how much your program will ate RAM. (100'000 ^ 2) / (1'024 ^ 3) in GB.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much

Comment: it's just a simple math expression to calculate the array size, can't you just do it yourself?

Comment: Ram is cheap, upgrade, you can get 16 gig for less than $100 now days

Comment: Why on earth do you need an array that big anyways?  Bad code smell.

Comment: @Ryios, I'm not sure more _physical_ memory will do any good here. There's long been a disconnect between physical and virtual memory so, even you you only had a gig, Windows should still allow you to allocate 1.1G (for example), using disk swapping to handle the over-allocation.

Comment: Well, first off, in .Net prior to 4.5 there is a 2gb limit to any memory allocation.  Meaning you cannot instantiate any object or type in a way as to consume more than 2GB of memory.  Regardless of how large the current working set is.  However in 4.5 you can set "gcAllowVeryLargeObjects" in your app.config and go as large as your machines working set will allow.  On my machine, with 16gb of ram and a 4gb page file I can allocate a 4gb Array before I get out of memory, likely because my VM's are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100,000 times 100,000 bytes is going to need about 10GB of space, it's unlikely you'll be able to allocate that in a 32bit OS, where you're limited to a 4G address space (and there are *other* things that will be using it as well).

Even if your heap *could* handle that (and it may be possible in a 64bit OS), you should think about it very carefully.

Instead, you may want to think about other options such as disk storage, bringing in only what's needed as you need it. This could be as simple as memory-mapping a 10G file and letting the OS handle paging of it to and from disk as needed.

Or, depending on your actual *needs* (rather than a specific implementation to meet those needs), there may be other ways.

Answer (score 1):

If using visual studios with .net 4.5 or higher. You can set your program build platform target to x64.

Then include the below in your App.Config file.

```
<runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

The above will let you use a jagged array like this and yes it will use 10gb of memory.

```
        byte[][] array = new byte[100000][];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new byte[100000];
        }
```

Edit: As said by paxdiablo this should not be used as there should be a better way to accomplish what you are trying. Also you need a 64 bit OS to be able to run the above.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes i figured that was obvious by x64 platform target. But you are right i should have stated that above. I added it above thanks pax.

Comment: allocating each row separately like that is very bad in terms of locality, and it's also slower than a single 2 dimentional array

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc what makes you think that allocating sequence of arrays will lead to significantly different memory layout (and hence locality) than one long array?